# Como puedo mostrar datos de un json en el atributo texto?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, d3.js

Quisiera poder mostrar los elementos del json en el atributo texto.
¿Habría alguna manera?

Solo quiero mostrar el nombre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
d3.json("js/data/actual.json").then(function(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
});

g_content_dropDown
  .append("text")
  .text("aqui mostrar el nombre")
  .attr("x", "30")
  .attr("y", "80")
  .style("fill", "#000000")
  .style("font-size", "18")
  .style("font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: Lo que entiendo de ese json es que es un array de objetos json. Por lo que tendrías que recorrer ese array o seleccionar el valor deseado y luego escoger el nombre de dicho objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya resolví mi problema, solo era recorrer el arreglo y obtener el objeto.

```
    d3.json("js/data/actual.json").then(function(data: any) {
  var dats;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dats = data[i]["nombre"];
    g_content_dropDown
      .append("text")
      .text(dats)
      .attr("x", "30")
      .attr("y", 80 + i * 30)
      .style("fill", "#000000")
      .style("font-size", "18")
      .style("font-weight", "bold");
  }
});
```